# TNS entry which will point to secondary database in-case primary is down

Tags: oracle, oracleclient, tnsnames, tns

I have two RAC databases which are in-sync with each other. The application we use does **only reads** from the database. We want to come up with a TNS entry which will **first try logging in to the primary RAC and if the connection fails it should connect to the secondary RAC**.

**Both RACs are up and running** and have a service running with the same name.

Once again, the application should not connect to the secondary RAC while the primary RAC is accessible.

Thanks in advance ... :)

The primary RAC TNS entry is

```
rac1=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (FAILOVER = ON)
    (ENABLE=BROKEN)
    (LOAD_BALANCE = ON)
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = rac1-host1)(PORT = 1521))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = rac1-host2)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = testdb)
      (FAILOVER_MODE =
        (TYPE = SELECT)
        (METHOD = BASIC)
        (RETRIES = 20)
        (DELAY = 2)
     )
    )
  )
```

and the secondary RAC TNS is

```
rac2=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (FAILOVER = ON)
    (ENABLE=BROKEN)
    (LOAD_BALANCE = ON)
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = rac2-host1)(PORT = 1521))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = rac2-host2)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = testdb)
      (FAILOVER_MODE =
        (TYPE = SELECT)
        (METHOD = BASIC)
        (RETRIES = 20)
        (DELAY = 2)
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: How are they kept in synch?  Generally. if using an Oracle tool, e.g. Data Guard, there is a recommended method to achieve this in the documetnation

Comment: They are kept in-synch manually. At night primary DB is updated and then a backup is taken at primary and the backup us restored in the secondary. No transactions takes place during the day time.

Comment: What happens if you add the rac2 address lines to the rac1 TNS entry and vica versa?

Comment: I forgot to add the LOAD_BALANCE parameter in the original question, sorry about that. With LOAD_BALANCE = ON, the sessions are shared among the two RAC setups ... :(

Comment: I'm not sure whether it helps. For active-standby, there is an option which make client to migrate to second site, if the 1st is not OPEN. But you have OPEN databases on both sides, don't you? Also I recall there is/was a product called Oracle connection manager, which acts like an connection proxy for oci protocol. Maybe this could be used for this purpose.

Comment: I cannot see an standard and automatic method to achieve what want.  But can you run DBMS_SERVICE.START_SERVICE and DBMS_SERVICE.START_STOP to enable and disable the server name on the unused RAC?  SO RAC one would have DBMS_SERVICE.START_SERVICE and RAC2 DBMS_SERVICE.START_STOP and vica versa.